# How to initialize a LiveData<> object to avoid a NullPointerException when trying to return a single record

Tags: android, android-room

I want to pull a single record from my Room database and can do so with a query in my Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Scenario WHERE id=:scenarioId")
LiveData<Scenario> getScenario(long scenarioId);
```

I only want to be update it in my ViewModel when there is a change:

```
final Observer<Scenario> scenarioObserver = new Observer<Scenario>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Scenario scenario) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + scenario.getId());
    }
};
```

When running I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference
```

but I can't initialize it the variable:

```
scenario = new LiveData<Scenario>();
```

because I get an error: LiveData is abstract; cannot be abstract.

How do I deal with this situation? How do I initialize the LiveData object?

**UPDATE**

I get this error from the compiler:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<com.behaviorotg.tokensystem1.model.ScenarioBehaviorTokenLog>).
```

On this line:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Scenario WHERE id=:scenarioId")
MutableLiveData<Scenario> getScenario (long scenarioId);
```

Comment: how are you calling `getScenario`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official document for `LiveData` at [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java)

You can initialize `LiveData` as follow.

In `Java`

```
    // This code should be in `ViewModel` class.
    // Create a LiveData with a String
    private MutableLiveData<String> currentName;

    public MutableLiveData<String> getCurrentName() {
        if (currentName == null) {
            currentName = new MutableLiveData<String>();
        }
        return currentName;
    }
```

In `kotlin`

```
    // Create a LiveData with a String
    val currentName: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
LiveData scenario = new MutableLiveData<Scenario>();
```

Comment: Can you please try to add some explanation to this code?

Comment: You already have that answer. Its the error message. LiveData is an abstract class, you cant make an instance of it. MutableLivedata is inherited from Livedata which you should use to create an instance and you can also update/post value to it.

Comment: Actually, if you want to post you have to use MutableLiveData scenario = new MutableLiveData<Scenario>();

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instantiate a live data here, just use the same instance that is returned by the query method.

If you need to instantiate it you can use MutableLiveData, but if you want to pass it from ViewModel to Activity/Fragment expose it as LiveData like this:

```
 // change it from main thread with set(value) and from other threads with post(value)
private MutableLiveData<Scenario> liveData = MutableLiveData()
// doing this will ensure that your view can't change its vlaue
public LiveData getLiveData() {
    return liveData
}
```